# What's the fastest charging power adapter for an iPhone 7 Plus?

Tags: charging, power, iphone

With my previous iPhone 6 Plus, it was recommended that I use a [12W adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD836LL/A/) and I found that (or at least convinced myself that) the phone charged faster with the 12W than with [the 5W](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD810LL/A/). However my iPhone 7 Plus ships with a 5W adapter.

- Can I charge my iPhone 7 Plus with a 12W adapter?
- Will my iPhone 7 Plus charge faster with a 12W adapter?

What's the fastest charging power adapter for an iPhone 7 Plus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason, Apple often chooses not to include the best charging option with its devices. This is particularly odd with 9.7” iPads, which ship with a 10W power adapter. Those haven’t been available for sale from Apple since 2013.

According to the [Apple Online Store](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD836LL/A/apple-12w-usb-power-adapter), the 12W USB Power Adapter is compatible with the iPhone 7 and 7+.

[image: 12W USB Power Adapter Compatibility]

**Both 4.7” and 5.5”** iPhones can use up to 10W power adapters to charge faster, as measured by an ammeter and **System Information**.

Either way, power is drawn by the “receiving” device, so there is no risk in using an adapter that provides more power. If the charger can provide the requested wattage, it does; otherwise, the highest power output is negotiated.

If you plug into a Mac’s USB port, your Mac will deliver 2.1A (10W) to iPads and to the larger iPhones (6 and above). It will deliver 500mA to WATCH and 1A to smaller iPhones (SE and lower).

I have tested this with a 2013 iMac. It is possible that newer Macs are able to provide 2.4A to iPads.

**Update 2017/03/22**: iPad 5 and iPad mini 4 now ship with a 12W power adapter. According to the [chosen verbiage](http://www.apple.com/shop/buy-ipad/ipad-9-7), this may be the standard going forward.

> **Which power adapter should I use to charge my iPad?**
>
> The 12.9-inch iPad Pro, 9.7-inch iPad Pro, iPad (5th generation), and
>   iPad mini 4 come with a 12W USB Power Adapter. Some previous iPad
>   models came with a 10W USB Power Adapter. If you need to purchase an
>   additional adapter, choose a 12W adapter because it can charge all
>   iPad models.

Comment: So basically any (approved) charger will work, and the higher wattage ones will (generally) charge faster?

Comment: That is generally correct. The 12W charger is pretty much a “universal” charger for Apple’s mobile devices. The main reason you wouldn’t want one is it might block the lower outlet, if you plug directly into the wall. But that can usually be worked around.

Comment: @Phong, You said "_The main reason you wouldn’t want one is it might block the lower outlet, if you plug directly into the wall._" and why would you even make a statement such as that since, if using the duckhead,  one can simply plug it in the lower socket of the duplex receptacle to begin with, thus leaving the upper socket free for use. There is no sensible reason to plug it in the upper socket if concerned about blocking the lower socket for use! This is just plain common sense.

Comment: They likely don't include it because it'll cause the battery to get hotter, thus overall reducing the battery longevity

Answer (score 3):

I did a comparison of charging devices with my iPhone 7 Plus, see the review here: http://www.genesgreenmachine.com/comparing-usb-chargers-using-iphone-7-plus/

What I found was the iPad 12 watt charger delivered about 10 watts to the iPhone 7 Plus, and there were several other chargers that produced similar wattage delivered to the iPhone 7 Plus.  I did this review more for personal reasons, as I use a pedal generator to charge my phone and wanted to know which charger put the most watts into my phone, making the most of my pedal charging time.

Comment: Make sure that you explicitly say that something you link to is yours. If you don't, this is going to be deleted, since it's spam.

Comment: It is mine entirely.  I created the site, personally did the review and believe it is relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Great. Now please [edit] your answer to contain an answer, rather than just a link to one -- see [How to Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 12W charger with iPhone 7 Plus. It will charge it much faster than a stock 5W charger. I have iPhone 7 Plus myself and using 12W charger all the time.
I measured many chargers and stopped on original Apple 12W iPad charger. Works the best for me.

You can measure the charge on your own phone with a free app - Amperes Lite.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amperes-lite-battery-charging/id1253789580?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 7 circuitry is able to handle the use of Qualcomm or other 2.4 amp chargers with a Lightning MFi Certified cable to charge quickly :)

Differences in how long it takes to charge are negligible when compared to the genuine charger and cable it ships with.